# Switch panels at the end of game in java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, netbeans-8

I searched but all the answers are about `cardlayout` and I experienced that `cardlayout` need a panel always visible to perform an action. I have this game.. [image]

and I want it to show a new panel with a message **Game Over** and with options

1. Play Again
2. Exit
   In the Same window when a sequence appear.
   I created a new class Named **`GameOver`** and in its constructor I created a panel and added the above options in it. And tried this out of the constructor or in a new method etc. **But** when I call this in the main Game Class it gives null pointer exception error
   **Update:** this is whole Stack Trace.

   ```
   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1091)
   at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:1003)
   at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:564)
   at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:415)
   at Tic_Tac_new.mouseClicked(Tic_Tac_new.java:132)
   at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6528)
   at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
   at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
   at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4542)
   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
   at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
   ```

   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 seconds)

please guid me how can I do this.
This is my main class condition to add `pGOver`

```
@Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

               if (e.getSource()== buttonsArray[0] && turn == true){
                        buttonsArray[0].setText("X");
                        turn = false;
                        checkXb1();
                        buttonsArray[0].setForeground(Color.red);
                        turntxt.setText(turnA);

//                        newGame.remove(mainGamePanel);
                        this.add(GameOver.pGOver);
                    }
```

Comment: can you post full StackTrace?

Comment: @user99370 I added and update check it please

Comment: `I  experienced that cardlayout need a panel always visible to perform an action.` and what is the problem with that? You have two panels 1) the game panel and 2) game finished panel. When the game is over the game panel is visible and then you swap to the "game over" panel so know it is visible. So only one panel is visible at a time. Is that not your requirement?

Comment: @camickr always means here is the same panel (single) should be visible at all the time to switch between other panels. But in my case I have no panel that will always be visible.

Comment: No you don't need one panel to always be visible. You program logic is responsible for determining which of the two panels is visible.

Comment: can you please give an example so that I proceed. All the example I visited required 1 panel always visible.